# How to extract the digest algorithm from a X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate

I can extract the OID and the name of the signature algorithm from a `X509Certificate` instance such as `"SHA256WithRSA"` but how do i extract the name of the digest algorithm like e.g. `"SHA256"`.

Is there a way beside a string splitting for `"with"` or a fixed mapping of the OID's?

Side question: Would it be safe to split for `"with"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certificate contains only the signature algorithm OID which maps to a unique couple digest/algorithm. Therefore the easiest way to found the digest algorithm is to use a mapping table OID -> digest algo.

Unfortunately I know no centralized location where you can find these OID. However they can be collected in these RFC:

- [Algorithms and Identifiers for the Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279)
- [Additional Algorithms and Identifiers for RSA Cryptography for use in the Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4055)
- [Updates for RSAES-OAEP and RSASSA-PSS Algorithm Parameters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5756)
- [Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure: Additional Algorithms and Identifiers for DSA and ECDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5758)

Parsing the algorithm name and splitting on "With" should work but with these limitations

- It may only work with Oracle Cryptography provider (see the documentation on [signature algorithm naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature)). Another provider, with its own certificate implementation, may use another incompatible naming convention.
- If the algorithm is unknown the `getSigAlgName()` method will return a String of the form `OID.a.b.c.d...`. For instance the `SHA256withDSA` algorithm is not supported by the old Java6 and will be printed `OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2`